# postgres & jsonb, list extraction (to table)

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following list stored in a JSON object in a `jsonb` table:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "p": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "p": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 789,
    "p": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 012,
    "p": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 345,
    "p": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 678,
    "p": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 901,
    "p": 7
  },
  {
    "id": 234,
    "p": 8
  },
  {
    "id": 567,
    "p": 9
  },
  {
    "id": 890,
    "p": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 1234,
    "p": 11
  },
  {
    "id": 5678,
    "p": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 9012,
    "p": 13
  }
]
```

I want a table with `id` and `p` columns, here having 13 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `json_array_elements`:

```
SELECT
    json_array_elements(data)->>'id' AS id,
    json_array_elements(data)->>'p' AS p
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo